# Does the Sigma MC-11 adapter work with the Sigma Canon Teleconverter?

Tags: sony, telephoto, sigma, teleconverter

I'm currently looking for tele lenses for Sony E mount.

I haven't settled on a camera body yet, but I'll probably get an a7c.

One option would be the Sigma 100-400mm for Sony E. Though without a Sigma E-mount teleconverter, 400mm would be the upper limit.

Another attractive option would be Sigma 150-600mm for Canon + MC-11.

**Does anyone have experience whether the combo `MC-11` + `TC-2001` (or alternatively `TC-1401`) + `150-600mm F5-6.3 DG OS HSM` works**?

That would be a really affordable 150-1200mm option.

I know that Sigma explicitly mentions MC-11 does not support tele converters, though that just means they can not guarantee anything, not that it won't work.

So I'm wondering if anyone has tested that combination.

Comment: Using a teleconverter makes the lens slower.  If you use a 2x teleconverter with the 600mm f/6.3 you get a 1200mm f/12.6.  That will require slow shutter speeds and probably make the autofocus not work.  This is independent of the question you have asked, which is why it is a comment.

Comment: This appears to be an [X→Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Rather than ask us what you think a solution to your real problem is, please tell us what it is you're trying to accomplish by coupling an MC-11 between a Sony α7C a 150-600mm lens in EF mount. If you're "reach limited", there are higher resolution cameras compared to the 24MP α7C that might be more appropriate. But we can't know for sure what might work best unless we know more specifically what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm a beginner hobbyist, so I'm looking for some affordable, versatile gear.

The use cases I envision are animal (bird) fotography in the local park and pictures of the moon.

Comment: Congratulations! You've picked two of the least affordable subjects to chase. Getting quality images at narrow angles of view/large distances can be expensive. There aren't any real shortcuts. But you can also spend a lot of money and still not have the right tools for the use case. Perhaps rather than asking about what you (a bit naively) think is a good budget friendly solution, you should ask what kinds of characteristics do cameras and lenses need to have to do birding and narrow field astro work? Or search through the many existing questions here that already address just that?

Comment: Sure, this is probably an instance of the X->Y problem, and I could search for other answers to different questions, but if anyone has all of ``a newer Sony body``, ``MC-11``, ``TC-2001`` and ``Sigma 150-600``, I'd be really interested in how that works. Just curious.

Comment: No one here has all that and uses it together, because experienced photogs know why they wouldn't want to try that.

Comment: With the TC-2001? Maybe. With the TC-1401 it's just plain wrong, Sigma sells that combo. My two questions are: does the MC-11 work at all with the teleconverters, and if so, is 2x-tc useable.